# jQuery animation after timer only working once

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I am making a web-based quiz, and I want leftScroll jQuery animation to be fired each time my timer bars width is set to 0.
However it only works the first time. I get that this is because it always targets the first `.qAnswers a` How do I get it to fire the next each time?

Link: http://www.carlpapworth.com/friday-quiz/#

JS:

```
timesUp();

function timesUp(){
            $('#timerBar').animate({'width':'0px'}, 1500, function(){
                nextQuestion(function(){
                    resetTimer();
                }); 
            });                 
}

function nextQuestion(event){
    var $anchor = $('.qAnswers a');
     $('#qWrap').stop(true, true).animate({
        scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).position().left
        }, 2000, function(){
            nextCount();
            $anchor = $anchor.next('.qContainer a');
        });  

}

function resetTimer(){
    $('#timerBar').css('width', '99%');
    timesUp();
}
```

I am using this JS for firing the animation when click an "answer":

```
$('.qAnswers li a').bind('click',function(event){
                    $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
                        var $anchor = $(this);
                        $('#qWrap').stop(true, true).delay(800).animate({
                            scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).position().left
                        }, 2000, function(){
                nextCount();
                        });
                        stopTimer();
                        event.preventDefault();
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

[Try this simplified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FwB4g/1/)

The problem is here :

```
nextQuestion(function(){
    resetTimer();
 });
```

You can't pass along a callback function to nextQuestion. I'm guessing you want to reset the timer when the nextQuestion is shown.

If that's the case, simply put `resetTimer()` in the call function of the `animate()`

Here's the code, you'll need to adapt it.

```
timesUp();

function timesUp() {
    $('#timerBar').animate({
        'width': '0px'
    }, 5000, function () {
        nextQuestion();

    });
}

function nextQuestion(event) {
    resetTimer();
    /*
    var $anchor = $('.qAnswers a');
    $('#qWrap').stop(true, true).animate({
        scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).position().left
    }, 2000, function () {
        nextCount();
        resetTimer();
        $anchor = $anchor.next('.qContainer a');
    });
    */

}

function resetTimer() {
    $('#timerBar').css('width', '100%');
    timesUp();
}
```

Comment: Resetting the timer bar is not the issue here. It works fine. The problem is the animation fired after, it only works the FIRST time.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a counter to know which anchor to choose :

```
var counter = 0;
function nextQuestion(event){
    var $anchor = $('.qAnswers a');

    // try to see the good anchor
    console.log($anchor[counter]);

     $('#qWrap').stop(true, true).animate({
        scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).position().left
        }, 2000, function(){
            nextCount();
            $anchor = $anchor.next('.qContainer a');
        }); 
     counter ++; 
}
```

Comment: Tried this, didn't get any result I'm afraid. It seems logic though, so I don't get why it doesn't work. (check the link if you want to, using your suggestion right now)